# Trying to apply a function on two lists

Tags: list, function, scheme, racket

I wrote the following code in order to apply a function for two lists
which are part of a list of lists but for some reason I'm getting `#<void>` values in the result.

The code:

```
(define (applyFunc list) 
    (cond ((null? list) ())
          ((null? (cdr list)) (car list))
          (else (cons (func (car list) (car (cdr list))) 
                (applyFunc (cdr (cdr list)))))))
```

`func` is a function that applies a function on two given lists

What I get from tracing my code is:

```
>(applyFunc '((1) (1 1) (1 1 1) (1 1 1 1)))

> (applyFunc '((1 1 1) (1 1 1 1)))

> >(applyFunc '())

< <'()

< '(#<void>)

<'(#<void> #<void>)

(#<void> #<void>)
```

[assuming the input was `'((1) (1 1) (1 1 1) (1 1 1 1))`]

Comment: It would be helpful to indent the (applyFunc (cdr (cdr list))) bit to align with the first item of the cons. I tried editing it but edits must be at least 6 non-empty characters for some reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with Oscar, above.  The main problem with your code was that on the empty case, you were returning `()` instead of `'()`.

In terms of your naming conventions, `list` should technically run just fine, but, as mentioned by Oscar, it is generally considered bad to run the risk of overwriting a built-in procedure.

I updated the code by changing the `()` to a `'()`, and it ran flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of errors to be taken care of first:

- You should not call `list` a procedure parameter (or anything else for that matter), since that's a built-in procedure in Scheme and you'd be overwriting it.
- In the first condition, the usual is to return `'()`, not `()`

Other than that, your procedure works fine:

```
(define (applyFunc lst) 
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
        (else (cons (func (car lst) (car (cdr lst))) 
                    (applyFunc (cdr (cdr lst)))))))
```

It's possible that the problem is in the `func` procedure, make sure that it does indeed work with two lists. I tested your code with this, and it worked without a hitch:

```
(define (func l1 l2)
  (append l1 l2))
```

Comment: I've also seen people use `xs` as a generic variable name for "some list". (Some people don't like how similar `lst` looks to `1st` in some fonts. (And in Scheme `1st` is a legal name. (Yes, I realize I'm excessively nesting parentheses in prose.)))